# How can I spread props to a React component that uses exact props when using Flow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Consider the following example using flow props.

```
import * as React from 'react';

type FooProps = {| 
  foo: number,
  bar?: string 
|};

class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps> {}
```

We have React component class `Foo` that accept an exact object of props. We want to enforce exactness so that users are not inadvertently making typos on their props (e.g. `baz` when they meant to use `bar`).

This works absolutely fine and errors happen as expected.

However, what if we want to spread props to this component from somewhere else? For example:

```
const f = (props: FooProps) => <Foo {...props} />;
```

Flow will give us an error about exactness on `props`:

```
10: const f = (props: FooProps) => <Foo {...props} />;
                                    ^ Cannot create `Foo` element because inexact props [1] is incompatible with exact `FooProps` [2].
References:
10: const f = (props: FooProps) => <Foo {...props} />;
                                   ^ [1]
8: class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps> {}
                                     ^ [2]
```

Disregarding the argument, "you shouldn't spread props to components like that when you're asking for exactness", how can spreading be achieved?

I did find one way to do this, but it uses an undocumented utility type `$Shape<T>` ([code](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/dc8f2001b3b2d1a2770150a3110374edeb43535e/src/typing/type_annotation.ml#L276)). It's unclear if this has any consequences or side effects, but it appears to work correctly:

```
class Foo extends React.Component<$Shape<FooProps>> {}
```

Here's a [link to try out what I've got using `$Shape<T>`](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAGIQQAKxY6AXjgBvAD5w6cOAS4AuOADsAriABGWKABpJcVcigB+eahhRgCgOYTRAX3p1cAGzTpOEOFgAeMLAoAm6Nh4MAB0AMIkkAq+MAA8ACQAygAWyKyxbrwQ-AB8OSI2DLgQCibScEIAFGB8qPKZtQCUFfkZXCIhnTXZqDZwAPQ59gSVwtJycACMAEwAzJq6+vJkyKq4ZHA2jfbFpfBjelpwnSGUZX1CB0vkM7NkCzIQ8reb9JVt7sInZzB9g40MfoIBCSJAAOXcGmIUHQqwgADc2DBksB0KgsPhgCVQXAAIKORxwCAEODItjqRwQADucCpwAJHig0NB-ToI2EW3o7PGT0USgZnLZo0WUGec022yKJTKVyg0wW3ywJmmmwqIhF0zF8x5WoWegAXstbhs7HR3m4Op0ftM-jlGkA) with items I expect to error (and not):

Comment: Doesn't the $Shape variant just make the component take inexact props, whereas your function takes exact?  So you've not solved the problem of making the component take exact props.  My understanding was that its unwise to create components that accept exact props.  Unreferenced props are not an issue.  Mistyping prop names means that the expected prop value, when required, is missing and therefore will produce an error.

Comment: @DaveMeehan That's exactly what I mean by $Shape having unintended consequences. Mis-typed optional props can be problematic, given various use cases. That kind of error can be small, like just a missing visual cue, or large, like a loss of revenue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apologies if this is not from an official source.

Solution: Type cast props to `any` before spread.

It meets your requirements of spread within a function.  The function ensures exactness prior to type casting.

NB: `$Shape<FooProps>` on the cast does not work, it still thinks its exact.  Neither does assigning `props` to a `const spreadable: $Shape<FooProps> = props`  It seems `$Shape` doesn't remove the exactness, despite appearances in your example.  One way or another, you have to strip the exactness, and doing it internally the function seems plausible.

[The Flow docs discuss type casting via `any` as legitimate](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/) although potential unsafe and not recommended (because you loose type safety).  I think in the context its reasonable.

```
import * as React from 'react';

type FooProps = {| 
  foo: number,
  bar?: string 
|};

class Foo extends React.Component<FooProps> {}

const f = (props: FooProps) => <Foo {...(props: any)} />;

f({foo: 1})                     // PASS: with foo, without bar
f({foo: 1, bar: ''})            // PASS: with foo and bar
{ <Foo foo={1} /> }             // PASS: with foo, without bar
{ <Foo foo={1} bar="" /> }      // PASS: with foo and bar

f({})                           // FAIL: missing foo
f({foo: ''})                    // FAIL: wrong type of foo
f({foo: 1, bar: 1})             // FAIL: with foo, wrong type of bar
f({foo: 1, x: 1})               // FAIL: unexpected x
{ <Foo /> }                     // FAIL: missing foo
{ <Foo foo="" /> }              // FAIL: wrong type of foo
{ <Foo foo={1} bar={1} /> }     // FAIL: with foo, wrong type of bar
{ <Foo foo={1} x={1} /> }       // FAIL: unexpected x
```

[Try it here](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAGIQQAKxY6AXjgBvAD5w6cOAS4AuOADsAriABGWKABpJcVcigB+eahhRgCgOYTRAX3p1cAGzTpOEOFgAeMLAoAm6Nh4MAB0AMIkkAq+MAA8brwQ-AB8IjYMuBAKJtJwQgAUYHyo8gnFAJR5qfFcIiH1hcXyyApM5TZwAPTJ9gT5wjIQ8gCMNuUAkJNTnZ1w3ACCAMqL8gDuwDAAFtJcmnDrWxBK8HpQdH0DcnDDe6fyZGRj07MLy2sb24Mo-rr6dMJwGruQYCYSjLqpGxTcYzOZLFb7D47CB7A6bI4nP4AoHI0Hg04CABEhIhcChMJe8PeW2R3z8vzO536T2hk1h7HmAEkADLyEDAVCocxWQZMy5DciPCbQ9lc3n7YiWODMVhwCAEZFiwYjW76EYstmzDk86mfXYKrJWFVsdUMrVXG5wTz66WGjhy+RKaKeVj4LD0zz-QFuUnkmVGj1wfmC4Wa7EhkHE0Ph90mi1K61qjWi+O1EFgjoEgvJimp+Vo5GoxVWlg2jWnIM4-Pgzx4jrdMlu43yr1eX0+AMMBhAA)

Comment: Thanks,  @dave-meehan. I appreciate the solution and I'm going to accept it as it seems like the only one without side-effects, other than the possibility of not typing the `props` argument on the `f` function correctly.

Comment: Tried multiple things to achieve that and this is the only working solution so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a very common issue: [Exact fails when doing es6 object spread](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2405)

One option suggested throughout that thread is to use:

```
type Exact<T> = T & $Shape<T>
```

Then *don't* write your types as exact with `{||}`:

```
type FooProps = {
  foo: number,
  bar?: string 
}

class Foo extends React.Component<Exact<FooProps>> {}
```

This will allow you to use the spread operator and still get auto-complete of properties.

Comment: Using this pattern has some issues in other places, so it's not a great solution to recommend, as it comes with a lot of "when and when not to use" [example](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwMbADwBUB8UC8V1QBkUAJAMoAWCkGmA3AFAOiRQAauUA3lEgFxQAdgFcAtgCMIAJygBfRgyQB7QQGdgUAGaDOACjAIpCUaoHxkaLggEiJ0gDRRxA9VICWggOaOAdH7aymACUuNhcskzaulYCAMyOzlAA5JpKSkmyQUA)

Comment: I see `Exact<T> = T & $Shape<T>` as a very weak exactness: It will behave like exactness in a world without spread, and it will be completely useless (i.e. equivalent to T) when restricted to a spread scenario.
So it's useful just when you want to protect your components from extra-props not originating from spread scenarios, but also not complain like $Exact, when spread is involved. I might be wrong :)